# get url value in C# mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, devexpress

I am getting below query string in my application from devEx. I am not gtting how to get all the filter values in Controller Action?

```
Home/Index?filter[0][]=Value&filter[0][]=%3D&filter[0][]=306
```

I am trying below code and it is not working for me.

```
public ActionResult Index(string[] filter)
{

}
```

Thanks

Comment: try by adding `/` after `Index`  like here `Home/Index/?filter[]=Value&filter[]==&filter[]=306`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Nuget package DevExtreme.AspNet.Data. It automatically populate and generate LINQ query based on the DevExtreme query string parameters.